# Exporting SQL data from server

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, ssh

I was working on a data modeling project. The client has an SQL database running on an active server but as an advancement and version updates, they need to use the Mongo database for effective data processing.

The client shared structured SQL data files (filename format: dump_.sql) over SSH connectivity. This SQL data should be populated on MongoDB. Please suggest the best steps to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're not actually exporting data from SQL Server, but rather importing it from dump_.sql file?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is an import or export operation. I just want to dump the SQL data into the Mongo database. Please suggest the steps to follow.

Comment: When you say "the SQL data", do you mean that you have a) `a file` or b) `a database server` where that data is located.

Comment: That's a server